# Getting visual studio to show the same API as Unity Hololens Development

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, uwp, hololens

When developing a Hololens UWP application using Unity 2017.2, the code completion in Visual Studio (2017) does not match what is available.

The dev environment is set up as described [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/Install_the_tools.html).

The UWP (Hololens) build [uses a subset of the API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt185501.aspx).  Visual studio code completion does not match this.

How do you set visual studio up correctly for this development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliSense should work normally when the dev environment is setup as described. Usually one of the following helps:

1. Restart Visual Studio and open the project again
2. Turn off Resharper if you have it enabled
3. Ensure you have a `using` statement for the namespaces for which you want IntelliSense

If none of these options helps, you can try reinstalling again according to the instructions.